# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused on Mac OS Catalina with XAMPP, tried most of the solutions on StackOverflow

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, xampp, macos-catalina

Recently I bought a Macbook and I want to run a laravel app using XAMPP. I downloaded the last available XAMPP for Mac OS, installed composer and successfully ran the project. Composer is working as expected, the local host is also working fine (when I try to access PhpMyAdmin it works). After that, I wanted to migrate using php artisan migrate **after** I created the database into PhpMyAdmin under the name web3project. I cloned my git repository containing the laravel application and edited the .env file:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:B8MsHk7bk84kwOl5HQebNY7c2UGLlDtpb/YbGl8HkYE=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=web3project
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

I tried editing

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
```

to

```
DB_HOST=localhost
```

The error I receive is:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = web3project and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

As I mentioned I am new to Mac OS and I may be doing something wrong with the XAMPP but the localhost is indeed working.

Comment: Don't use 127.0.0.1, it will try to use a network connection. If properly configured, the database will not have any network connectivity. Use localhost instead, which will connect via local socket.

Comment: Also there's no need to put values into `config/database.php` if you already have them in your `.env` file. But you should be setting uft8mb4 as a charset in that file, not utf8.

Comment: Doesn't matter in this case, I tried a few times with localhost instead of 127.0.0.1 but it gives me the same exact error even after php artisan config:cache and php artisan cache:clear commands executed before the migration.

Comment: It would not give you the same error because it would not be attempting a network connection. **Something is cached somewhere, or you are not editing the correct file.**

Comment: I just tried editing it to localhost and cleared the cache again and after that I tried to migrate. The error is exactly the same.

Comment: Correction: it is not exactly the same error.
PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=web3project", "root", "", [])
changes to:
PDO::__construct("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=web3project", "root", "", [])

Comment: try to log into the database with those credential using something like mySQLWorkbench and see if it have any problem to create the connection... also delete manually all the files inside bootstrap/cache

Comment: Open your terminal and try: `mysql -u root -p` then hit enter when prompted for the password. Are you able to connect to the database?

Comment: You would not get "connection refused" on a socket connection.

Comment: Yes, it is not connection refused, my bad, it is No such file or directory!

Comment: Set `DB_SOCKET` in your `.env` file to location specified in the MySQL config file.

Comment: I found the socket path and added it to the .env file as: *DB_SOCKET=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock* but it gives a "No such file or directory" error.

Comment: And does `ls -l /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock` confirm it's there?

Comment: No, it is not there. At this point I thought of changing to MAMP but again the error is "No such file or directory". The settings are exactly the same as on my Windows machine.

Comment: Update: I changed to MAMP and after that I edited the **DB_SOCKET** to /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock. That gave me another error: **SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'**
I changed the **DB_PASSWORD** to root, cleared the cache and migrated and it finally worked.